# How to get_terms() only of terms matching an ACF meta value?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, terms

My custom taxonomy "`company`" has an Advanced Custom Fields field group with fields including a [Checkbox](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/), "`tags`". (This adds to each "`company`" term fields including "tags", which accepts multiple string values corresponding to checkbox items).

I need to gather several groups of terms whose "`tags`" values include particular distinct values, eg. "Publishing", "Media", "Advertising.

So far, I have the following method, in which I cycle through all "`company`" terms and, if the string is found, add that term's ID to an array, used later to get actual term objects...

```
// Pick a focus tag (choose from 'Tags' ACF Checkbox values in the Organisation field)
$tag_section = "Publishing";

// First, get all organisation terms
$organisations = get_terms( 'company' );

// Initialise array we will use to store only matching organisations
$orgs_filtered = array();

// Make an array with only IDs of organisations with a matching tag
foreach ($organisations as $organisation) {
   // Construct prefixed object ref for this organisation
   $org_id_prefixed = 'company_'. $organisation->term_id;
   // If the intended value matches the target value
   if(in_array($tag_section, get_field('tags', $org_id_prefixed))){
      // add its term ID to our array - use this array to feed a WP_Query or similar
      array_push($orgs_filtered, $organisation->term_id);
   }
}
```

... But this only gives me an array of the **IDs** of matching terms - not an array **of the terms* themselves.

It feels like my method is cumbersome, and that it should be possible to make the above more efficient *and* get the actual term objects themselves.

I have read about [using `meta_query` with `get_posts` via ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) and I am familiar with WordPress' `get_terms()`. So I am hopeful it is possible to use a similar method.

But, when I try the following test in pursuit, it returns nothing from `$my_terms`...

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'company',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key'       => 'tags',
            'value'     => 'Publishing',
            'compare'   => '='
         )
    )
);
$my_terms = get_terms($args);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($my_terms);
echo '</pre>';
```

Thinking perhaps the 'value' should be an array, I changed the value part to `'value'     => array('Publishing'),` ...

But then that just shows ALL "`company`" terms from the site, with no matching in effect.

I have also tried both variations with a `compare` value of `in`.

Do you have any ideas about this?

Thanks.

Comment: The last example on the checkbox documentation page you linked above shows how to use a meta query. It has to be a `LIKE` comparison because it's stored as a serialized array.

Comment: Ah-hah, yes, the formulation is... `                  array(
                     'key'       => 'tags',
                     'value'     => 'Publishing',
                     'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                  )`